# Cereal: how to manage the implementation struct for the PIMPL idiom

Tags: c++11, serialization, visual-studio-2015, pimpl-idiom, cereal

I am having troubles to use `cereal` with the PIMPL idiom.

This is a minimal example:

*b.h*

```
#ifndef _B_H_
#define _B_H_

#include <memory>
#include "cereal/types/memory.hpp"
#include "cereal/archives/json.hpp"

struct BImpl;

class B
{
public:
    B();
    ~B();

private:
    std::unique_ptr<BImpl> _impl;

    friend class cereal::access;

    template <class Archive>
    void serialize( Archive& ar )
    {
        ar( CEREAL_NVP( _impl ) );
    }
};

#endif
```

*b.cpp*

```
#include "b.h"

struct BImpl
{
     int b_i = 0;

private:
    friend class cereal::access;

    template <class Archive>
    void serialize( Archive & ar )
    {
        ar(
            CEREAL_NVP( b_i )
          );
    }
};

B::B() : _impl( new BImpl )
{
}

B::~B()
{
}
```

*main.cpp*

```
#include "b.h"
#include <fstream>
#include "cereal/archives/json.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    B b1;
    {
        std::ofstream file( "out.json" );
        cereal::JSONOutputArchive archive( file );
        archive( CEREAL_NVP( b1 ) );
    }
}
```

And here the errors that I get on MSVC 2015 Community Edition when I try to compile the minimal example:

- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\type_traits(428): error C2139: 'BImpl': an undefined class is not allowed as an argument to compiler intrinsic type trait '__is_polymorphic'
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\type_traits(435): error C2139: 'BImpl': an undefined class is not allowed as an argument to compiler intrinsic type trait '__is_abstract'

I am quite sure that I am not the first attempting to do this, but I have not been able to find nothing specific in the [documentation](http://uscilab.github.io/cereal/quickstart.html) or code snippets with a working solution.

Comment: I have no error when compiling a minimal version without cereal included. What lines in your code are associated with the errors in type_traits? Try to comment the cereal integration and compile the code step by step: inclusion of cereal headers, friend declarations, serialize declarations, serialize use

Comment: The errors go away if you comment the row `archive( CEREAL_NVP( b1 ) );` in the `main.cpp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a working solution following the approach described here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/serialization/doc/pimpl.html

In practice, I have:
* moved the definition of `B::serialize` to `B.cpp`
* added in `B.cpp` all the different instantiations for the archives that I use

Here the ticket that describe the issue: https://github.com/USCiLab/cereal/issues/324

Comment: A more recent reference [here](http://lewismanor.blogspot.fr/2014/04/boost-serialization-part-2-handlepimpl.html). Indeed, 10 years later it looks like there is nothing new. You can accept your own answer ;)